# Passing argument 2,3 makes pointer from integer without a cast

Tags: c, pointers, casting

Using the language C and Netbeans 8.0.2  I'm trying to read a set of characters, of two files and pass those characters to a method called Patmat which is used to compare them.

The Patmat method has three arguments.The int argument is the number of mismatches that could have and other two character arguments are the file contents.

Below is the Patmat method which I got from an article and there is a long process inside it to compare.

```
int Patmat(int k, char *pattern, char *text){
}
```

Here is my main method

```
int main() {   
    FILE *fp1;
    FILE *fp2;

    char c;
    char c2;

    fp1= fopen ("file1.txt","r");
    fp2= fopen("file2.txt","r");

    while(1)
    {
        c = fgetc(fp1);
        if(c==EOF)
            break;
        else
            printf("%c", c); 
    }

    while(1)
    {
        c2 = fgetc(fp2);
        if(c2==EOF)
            break;
        else
            printf("%c", c2); 
    }
    fclose(fp1);
    fclose(fp2); 
    **// Patmat(0,&c,&c2);
    Patmat(0,c,c2);**
    return 0;   
}
```

As i'm not much familiar with C and pointers can anyone help me to pass those character sets of two files to the Patmat method? It does not work as above.

The content of two files are :

```
file1.txt: AGGTACCGTA
file2.txt: AGGTACCGTA
```

I directly passed those arguments as `Patmat(0,"AGGTACCGTA","AGGTACCGTA")`. It worked fine and returned the answer as 1 which is correct.

But now I want to read those character sets from a file and pass them to the Patmat method. It gives the following warning:

```
warning: passing argument 3 of 'Patmat' makes pointer from integer without a cast
 warning: passing argument 2 of 'Patmat' makes pointer from integer without a cast
```

Thanks in advance and sorry if I made any inconvenience. This is my first attempt to post a question here.

Comment: What do you expect these two `while`-loops to do?

Comment: Run the code in a debugger and trace it line by line inspecting the relevant variable. On how to do this reading this http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ might get you started.

Comment: `c` and `c2` aren't character sets, they're single characters.

Comment: Thanks, but what i'm saying is all the characters in the file1.txt are assigned to the variable c as c= 'AGGTACCGTA' and characters in the file2.txt are assigned to the variable c2 as c2='AGGTACCGTA'. Thats why I refferred them as character set. Sorry if i done a mistake. It prints nicely c and c2 but i can't pass them to the method. Would it be possible to use & sign as Patmat(0,&c,&c2). But it did not work. Thank you

Comment: @asw: A `char` variable is a single byte, it can only contain single character.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
while(1)
    {
        c = fgetc(fp1);
        if(c==EOF)
            break;
        else
            printf("%c", c); 
    } // By the time this loop breaks c will be EOF

    while(1)
    {
        c2 = fgetc(fp2);
        if(c2==EOF)
            break;
        else
            printf("%c", c2); 
    } // similar applies to this loop c2 EOF
    fclose(fp1);
    fclose(fp2); 
    **// Patmat(0,&c,&c2);
    Patmat(0,c,c2);// This section is not probably well equipped to provide correct results,  becuase of the EOF
```

I suspect what you are looking for is something like this

```
while( ((c = fgetc(fp1)) != EOF ) &&
       ((c2= fgetc(fp2)) != EOF ) ) {
               printf("%c %c", c, c2); 
               Patmat(0,&c,&c2); 
}
```

by the time you break this loop either both files are read completely or one of them still not at EOF, these cases required to be handled in here.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to read the entire file a `char` (one character) is not what you want. In that case you want to read the contents of the files into an array.

```
char *buffer[1024]; // for example
int result = fread(buffer, 1, 1024, fp1);
```

Now buffer contains your file contents which can be passed to your Patmat function

```
Patmat(0, buffer, buffer2); // buffer2 goes the same way
```

If you want to read the whole file in once (useful for smaller files) you can also allocate `buffer` dynamically. Also make sure to set the null terminator.

---

**Update:** an example would be:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define BUFSZ 32

void patmat(int k, char *pattern, char *text) {
    /* Compare or do something here */
    printf("K %d\nPattern %s\nText %s\n", k, pattern, text);
}

int main(int argc, char *agrv[]) {
    FILE *fp1 = NULL;
    FILE *fp2 = NULL;

    char buffer[BUFSZ];
    char buffer2[BUFSZ];

    if (!(fp1 = fopen("file1.txt","r"))) {
        perror("open file");
        return 1;
    }
    if (!(fp2 = fopen("file2.txt","r"))) {
        perror("open file");
        return 1;
    }

    size_t result = fread(buffer, 1, BUFSZ, fp1);
    if (!result)
        puts("reading error");

    size_t result2 = fread(buffer2, 1, BUFSZ, fp2);
    if (!result)
        puts("reading error");

    buffer[result-1] = '\0';
    buffer2[result2-1] = '\0';

    patmat(0, buffer, buffer2);

    fclose(fp1);
    fclose(fp2);
    return 0;
}
```

This is just an example, there are other/better ways.

Comment: This would be quiet useful. Thank you

Comment: I can give you the full example if that would help

Comment: Yes thank you, because next I should develope my program to compare larger files.